# AngularJS/Karma - unit test function in directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, directive

How can I unit test a function inside a directive's link? I tried something like this, but not worked:

directive:

```
app.directive("hello", function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope){
      scope.hello = function(){
        return "hello";
      };
    }
  };
});
```

unit test:

```
describe("Hello directive", function(){
  var compile, scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    compile = $compile;
  }));

  it("should return hello", function(){
    var element = compile("<hello></hello>")(scope);
    expect(element.scope.hello()).toBe("hello");
  });
});
```

Comment: Define "not worked". Why use `element.scope.hello()` and not simply `scope.hello()`? Also, element.scope is a function returning the scope of the element, as documented: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element. So it should be `element.scope().hello()`.

Comment: The result with element.scope().hello() is the same: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'element.scope().hello()')"

Comment: And with scope.hello(), too.

Comment: Your directive is not applied, because its default restrict is 'A'. So you would need `<div hello></div>` for this directive to be applied. Set the restrict field to 'E' if you want the directive to be applied using `<hello></hello>`

Comment: That's correct. One more command failed in the test: beforeEach(module("myApp")); Now it's working. If you write it down in the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a call to `module`.

The directives restrict looks *just fine (nowadays)* as the default is `'EA'` as per the [angular source for $compileProvider](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L852).

> **Note:** Said default was introduced in angular-1.3.0([commit: 11f5ae](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/11f5aeeee952a395edaf54e3277674f211a82fc7), [PR: 8321](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/8321)), prior to that version it was simply `'A'`. Which would have been an issue in your case, seeing as how your question was posted in May'14.

I setup a fiddle showcasing your implementation with two changes;

- A call to `module`, so as to load your directive definition.
- Bumped the angular version to `1.3.0`.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2khrafvz/3/)**

---

*yes I'm late to the party, but your question remains one of the top unanswered questions in [angularjs]+[unit-testing]. figured I'd have a go at changing that.*